# curl stuck on same page

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to a page, and then go to a different page, submit a form, and then I get another form on the same link, submit that, and then get another form on the same link, and submit that.

However, from what I see, I login fine ... but after that it keeps showing me the same page (the one after I login).

```
 $username = 'xxxxxxx';
    $password = 'yyyyyyy';
    $useragent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

    $fields = array(
        'username='. urlencode($username),
        'password=' . urlencode($password),
    );
    $postdata = implode('&', $fields);

    $ch = curl_init();

    //Main Login
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/index.php");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/index.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo $result;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($info);
    echo "</pre>";
    print curl_error($ch);

$contractid = "12345";
$fields = array(
    'contract_id='. urlencode($contractid),
    'submit='. urlencode("Next"),
);
$postdata2 = implode('&', $fields);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/index.php?page=Recovery");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/index.php?page=Recovery");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata2);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result_2 = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo $result;
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($info);
echo "</pre>";
print curl_error($ch);
```

and twice more for each step, the same way and ending it with `curl_close($ch);`.

However, like I stated, it still shows only the main page.

Comment: Maybe give Selenium a try instead of Curl.

Answer (score 0):

After first curl request close curl and initialize again. Otherwise curl will not write anything to cookie file and at next call no cookies are sent!

> CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR
>
> The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is
> closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

```
// after end of first curl call
curl_close($ch);

// before second curl call
$ch = curl_init();
```

Comment: Tried that, still the same thing. However, I do see the page showing http code 200 on the next page, but still content wise it shows main page ...

`Array
(
    [url] => https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/index.php?page=Recovery
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 200`